# Why does the output differ for tm package and RTextTools package?

Tags: r, sparse-matrix, tm

I have a dataset of 260 RTI applications. I am supposed to perform LDA on them. I have created the term-doc matrix using tm as well as RTextTools package. However, the output differs greatly. Tm package doesn't show any sparse entry counts. The number of total terms differs greatly.
Here is the code:

```
library("tm")
library("RTextTools")
<I read the data here into a variable called 'data'>
doc = Corpus(VectorSource(data))
m = create_matrix(data, language = "english", removeNumbers = TRUE, removePunctuation = TRUE, stemWords = TRUE, weighting = weightTf) #RtextTools statement
tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(doc, control = list(removePunctuation = TRUE, removeNumbers = TRUE, language = "english", stemWords = TRUE, stopWords = TRUE, weighting = weightTf) #tm statement
>m
#<<DocumentTermMatrix (documents: 260, terms: 951)>>
Non-/sparse entries: 2669/244591
Sparsity           : 99%
>tdm
#<<TermDocumentMatrix (terms: 1024, documents: 1)>>
Non-/sparse entries: 1024/0
Sparsity           : 0%
```

If you need the dataset to understand the problem better, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

See `?termFreq` - it has got to be `stemming=TRUE, stopwords=TRUE` instead of `stemWords = TRUE, stopWords = TRUE`. Also note that a `SimpleCorpus` object triggers a default behavior for `TermDocumentMatrix` that may override your control parameters.

Comment: So you suggest using VCorpus?

Comment: @HimabinduBoddupalli yes.

Comment: doc = VCorpus(VectorSource(data))                                                                   
tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(doc, control = list(language = "english", removeNumbers = TRUE, removePuncutation = TRUE, stemming = TRUE, stopWords = TRUE, weighting = weightTf)) Still does not work.

Comment: @HimabinduBoddupalli Did you read my answer? There is no control parameter `stopWords`.

Comment: @HimabinduBoddupalli Then please edit your original post and make it a minimal reproducible example including `data` to showcase both give different results.